# Create an association with OpenShift OpenID and AWS without manual mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, openshift

I have an Openshift cluster I installed on AWS with the redhat script (without ROSA).
I wish to have Iam Role for Service Account (IRSA) so the pod I create can use temporary AWS credential.

For this I understand that I need to have my cluster running in Manual Mode for the credentialsMode. It seems possible to update my cluster to use manual even after creation.
But my problem is I wish to update my credential one after the other, and I do not care (for now) of the role managed by openshift it self (such as Installer, Worker ...)

Is there a way to make an association between my openShift cluster OpenID and AWS Identity Provider without switching to manual mode ?